# Align Materials to same widths and heights without a Table

Tags: flutter

I created a material for my app which should enclose some text. It looks like this:

[image: Default look]

Sometimes, there is overflowing text. With a flexible it looks like this:

[image: Flexible Active on Renderoverflow]

And I also want it to align like in a Table. Without alignment to the others it looks like this:

[image: These should get aligned in width]

The Border between the colors should be at the same position for all of those elements so it looks clean.

How can I achieve all of this? The Flexible Widget throws a WrongParent Exception when Put into a Table.

My Code:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'nook_constants.dart';

class NookTable extends StatelessWidget {
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final EdgeInsets margin;
  final Widget child;
  final String title;
  final String text;
  final String font;

  NookTable({
    this.width,
    this.height,
    this.margin: nookDefaultMargin,
    this.child,
    this.title,
    this.text,
    this.font
  });

  final cell = (Widget widget) => Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 5, bottom: 5, right: 15),
      child: widget,
    );
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var margin = EdgeInsets.only(
      left: this.margin?.left ?? 0.0,
      right: this.margin?.right ?? 0.0,
      top: this.margin?.top ?? 0.0,
      bottom: max(2, this.margin?.bottom ?? 0.0),
    );

    return Container(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 5, bottom: 5, right: 15),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          NookTitleDetails(text: title, width: width,),
          NookTextDetails(text: text,),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NookTextDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final String font;

  NookTextDetails({
    this.text,
    this.font
  });

  final cell = (Widget widget) => Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 5, bottom: 5, right: 15),
      child: widget,
    );
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flexible(
      child: Material(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(25), topRight: Radius.circular(25)),
        color: nookBeige,
        child: cell(Text(text))
      ),
    );
  }
}
class NookTitleDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final String font;
  final double width;

  NookTitleDetails({
    this.text,
    this.font,
    this.width
  });

  final cell = (Widget widget) => Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 5, bottom: 5, right: 15),
      child: widget,
    );
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: width,
      child: Material(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25), topLeft: Radius.circular(25)),
        color: nooklightGreen,
        child: cell(Text(text, style: TextStyle(color: nookWhite)))
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use row instead of a table. Then use flexible and expandable with the corresponding flex values.

Comment: The materials are in a row already. Expanded only works horizontally

Comment: Then put a column also inside the row and expandable in the column. Then it will work vertically.

Comment: You have to put a specific width to keep the border in the same position. Assuming the text to the left (Fundort), wrap with a container widget and put a specific width and then wrap the whole container inside a Flexible widget. The text to the right should be inside an Expandable widget.

Comment: I wrapped the left one into a container into a Flexible. The right one into an Expanded. It looks almost exactly like the second picture of my post

Comment: add code like this ....... Flexible(flex:0)   and   Expandable(flex:1) //change the flex value and find the desired needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
Container(

              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.lime,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))

              ),

              child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Stack(

                          children: <Widget>[Container(
                            width: 100,


                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              child: Text('Fundort',textAlign: TextAlign.center,))],
                        )),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 4,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.lightGreen,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(right:Radius.circular(10))

                        ),

                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Text('Sign in with FacebookSign in with Facebook',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white)),
                      ),
                    )
                  ]),
            ),
```

Comment: It works fine but has this little ugly edge on the right side: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/715595862415245333/717449084860104785/unknown.png

Answer (score 0):

```
               Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 0,
                      child: Container(
                                    width:100,
                                    child:Text('Text to the left')
                                     )
                                  ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 4,
                     child:Text('Text to the right')


                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: This is how its looking after I made your adjustments: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/715595862415245333/716773423766044821/unknown.png and https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/715595862415245333/716773284234133594/unknown.png

Comment: Is there any Idea on the right side overflowing in height? Otherwise your idea seems to work

Comment: Can you see this link?
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/715595862415245333/716779711685984316/unknown.png

Comment: The left and right part still do not fit in height quite correctly. And I have no Idea how I could connect those 2